# After set minute I see more than I set (countdownt timer)

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi I am making countdown timer. And when I put value of minutes less than one minute everything works correctly. But when I put value for example 1:05 min and click start I see counting down from 1:44. And this problem always appears when I put value bigger than 1 minute

```
//rundowy czasomierz {
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInput, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
            tv4.setText((round_count[0]+1)+"/"+finalNum_rounds);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            round_count[0]++;
            if (round_count[0]<finalNum_rounds){
                Handler handler=new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        start();
                    }
                }, przerwasinput);
            }
            MediaPlayer ring = MediaPlayer.create(Main6Activity.this, R.raw.ring1);
            ring.start();
            tv3.setText("Przerwa");
            if (!tv1.equals("00:00")) {
                tv1.setText("Koniec");
            }

private void updateCountDownText(){
    int hours = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
    int minutes = (int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted;
    timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    tv1.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that your program interprets an input of 1:05 as 105 seconds. This is equal to 1 minute and 45 seconds, so your timer would begin counting down from 1:45.

I don't see where in your code you process input, so I don't know exactly what is causing this.